# Jquery Select2 is working slow for larger number of lists.How to reduce the time or how to improve it?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm using Jquery select2 in a simple html programme.When I'm clicking on it the dropdown is displaying late. It is taking nearly 6 seconds to open.I've 2000 list items.So please help me how to resolve it.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Post your code. This might depend on how you're querying your data (AJAX or whatever), not the way the dropdown is generated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, in our scenario is was acceptable to have a searchable list so for lists where we knew the size could be large we utilised the ajax functionality to load the data on the fly.

```
$("#companySearchBox").select2({
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        allowClear : true,
        placeholder: "Search For Company",
        formatInputTooShort: function (input, min) { return "Start typing to search"; },
        ajax: {
            url: (crmServiceUrl + '/GetFilteredCompanies'),
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function (term) {
                return {
                    term: term
                };
            },
            type: "POST",
            results: self.ConvertData
        },
        initSelection: function (element, callback) {
            var data = [];
            var selected = element.val().split("|", 2);
            if (selected.length) {
                //element.val(selected[0]);
                callback({ id: selected[0], text: selected[1] });
            }
        },
        valueIdOnly : false
    });

    this.ConvertData = function (data) {
    var returnData = { results: [] }
    if (data.d.DataObject) {
        $.each(data.d.DataObject, function (key, value) {
            returnData.results.push({ id: value.Identity, text: value.Description });
        });
    }
    return returnData;
}
```

The ConvertData function, simply knows how to map from our custom data objects to the select items.

This may not be suitable for your needs but it was the only way I could really optimize for large collections of data.